# How to install SDL on Windows 8.1 and to connect it to Visual Studio Community 2013

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sdl

I need to install SDL and apply it to my Visual Studio if possible. So far, I have downloaded the Source Code file, Runtime Binaries (Windows x64 AND Visual C++ SDL Development Libraries.

What do I do after this? The download files are just sitting my computer. Sorry, I am quite new to all this.

Comment: lazyfoo.net has tutorials for every platform and IDE for how to setup SDL. The site has an explanation for VS2010, but the procedure is pretty much the same for VS2013

Comment: This is the link: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/msvsnet2010u/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use C/C++ libraries like `SDL2` in Visual Studio by adding `include` folder containing header files, and `lib` which contains library files, in your project settings. There is a visual tutorial here:

http://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/15/lesson-0-visual-studio/

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea there was an SDL library in VS.

Comment: Your welcome. You should know that there are other ways to do this. For example `NuGet` is a package manager for libraries that helps you so much. See an example for OpenGL: http://in2gpu.com/2014/11/29/setting-opengl-visual-studio-using-nuget/

Comment: Looks interesting. Thanks for your help.